# Various simple JavaScript solutions

Tags: javascript

Please critique my solutions to these simple exercises. I have no programming experience, so the more anal you are, the more I'll learn. I'm teaching myself, this is not for school:

> Write a function `translate()` that will translate a text into
>   "rövarspråket". That is, double every consonant and place an
>   occurrence of "o" in between. For example, `translate("this is fun")`
>   should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".

```
var translate = function(x) {
  var string = x.toLowerCase();
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", " "];
  var y = "";
  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     var current = string.charAt(i); 
    if (vowels.indexOf(current) != -1)
    y = (y + (current));
   else 
    y = (y + (current + "o" + current));
  }
  return y;
}
```

> Define a function `sum()` and a function `multiply()` that sums and
>   multiplies (respectively) all the numbers in an array of numbers. For
>   example, `sum([1,2,3,4])` should return 10, and `multiply([1,2,3,4])`
>   should return 24.

```
var sum = function(array) {
  var length = array.length;
  var total = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    total += array[i];
  }
  return total;
};

var multiply = function(array) {
  var length = array.length;
  var total = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < length;  i++) {
    total *= array[i];
  }
  return total;
};
```

> Define a function `reverse()` that computes the reversal of a string.
>   For example, `reverse("jag testar")` should return the string "ratset
>   gaj".

```
var reverse = function(string) {
  var length = string.length;
  var reversed = [];
  var joined = ("");
  for (i = length; i > 0; i--){
    reversed.push(string.charAt(i-1));
  };
  for (i = 0; i < (length) ; i++){
    joined += (reversed[i]);
  }
  return joined;
}
```

> Write a function `findLongestWord()` that takes an array of words and
>   returns the length of the longest one.

```
var findLongestWord = function(array) {
  var elements = array.length;
  var count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    if (array[i].length > count) 
      count = array[i].length;
  }
  return count;
}
```

> Write a function `filterLongWords()` that takes an array of words and
>   an integer `i` and returns the array of words that are longer than
>   `i`.

```
var filterLongWords = function(array, int){
  var length = array.length;
  var longestWords = [];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (array[i].length > int) {
      longestWords[longestWords.length] = array[i];
    }
  }
  return longestWords;
}
```

> Write a function `charFreq()` that takes a string and builds a
>   frequency listing of the characters contained in it. Represent the
>   frequency listing as a JavaScript object. Try it with something like
>   `charFreq("abbabcbdbabdbdbabababcbcbab")`.

```
var charFreq = function(string){
  var list = {};
  var length = string.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
  if (string.charAt(i) in list) 
    list[string.charAt(i)] += +1;
  else 
    list[string.charAt(i)] = 1;
  }
  return list;
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that rather than use global methods, I tried to as much as possible code for the result I wanted, like reverse, and join, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I've upvoted your question (+5!), but I think you should break this down into multiple questions - not because of the length (even more than that is still perfectly fine), but because it's really *multiple unrelated pieces of code*. The more questions you ask, the more upvotes you'll get, the more answers will appear, more votes, more happiness, joy! [cough] .. you'll like it here ;)

Comment: FYI, the reverse string one is SUPER easy `function reverseString(value) { return value.split('').reverse().join(''); }`

Answer (score 4):

Here one way to sum a list of integers using ECMAScript 5's functional support

```
// Sum all values in a list by reducing the list to a single value
array.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return prev + curr;
});
```

Not faster than your approach due to the repeated function calls, but definitely shorter.

Your approach can be further simplified:

```
// Move everything into the parenthesis of for-loop!
var sum = function(array) {
  for (
    var i = 0, len = array.length, total = 0; 
    i < len; 
    total += array[i++]
  );
  return total;
};
```

Not recommended because it's not very readable. I just think it's interesting :)

I'll give you an alternative approach to the "Find length of longest string" problem:

```
// Sort it by length descending and then get the first
var longestStrLen = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    a.length - b.length;
})[0].length;
```

Hope these open your eyes to some of the possibilities!

Now, here's an *actual* review:

```
var charFreq = function(string){
  var list = {}; // Not a list (implies order). Should name it a dictionary or map
  var length = string.length; // no need to have this be separate line
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {  
  if (string.charAt(i) in list) 
    // What's with the +1??
    list[string.charAt(i)] += +1;
  else 
    // No need to call string.charAt multiple times!
    list[string.charAt(i)] = 1;
  }
  return list;
}
```

Revised version:

```
var charFreq = function(string){
  var dict = {}; 
  for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i++) {
    var currChar = string.charAt(i);  
    if (currChar in dict) { 
      dict[currChar] += 1;
    } else {
      dict[currChar] = 1;
    }
  }
  return dict;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I find ++ both easier to read and more idiomatic -- in particular `for(i=0; i<X; i++)` is probably one of the most common code snippets on the face of the planet, with the only minor variation in X and whether you have to declare i or not.

Comment: yeah I agree. It's definitely more idiomatic, esp. in a for-loop. Outside of a for loop I prefer using +=1 b/c I find it more explicit hence readable.

Answer (score 4):

I'd start by pointing out that you forgot to declare your loop variables, so they become global, you need `var`:

```
for (var i; ...
    --^--
```

Also you forgot a few semicolons after your function expressions, [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) will tell you about these common errors.

But your code looks good, although maybe not very JavaScript-ish. Targeting ES5 compliant browsers (IE9+) you could simplify your code, so instead of using `for` loops, you'd use built-in higher-order functions, such as [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var sum = function(xs) {
  return xs.reduce(function(x, y){return x + y});
};

var multiply = function(xs) {
  return xs.reduce(function(x, y){return x * y});
};

var reverse = function(x) {
  return x.split('').reverse().join('');
};

var findLongestWord = function(xs) {
  return Math.max.apply(0, xs.map(function(x){return x.length}));
};

var filterLongWords = function(xs, i) {
  return xs.filter(function(x){return x.length > i});
};

var charFreq = function(x) {
  return x.split('').reduce(function(acc, x) {
    acc[x] = ++acc[x] || 1;
    return acc;
  },{});
};
```

For code that is very generic I prefer to use short variables names such as `xs`, `x`, `y`, etc. These are inspired by other functional languages, and are well understood, but you could always add JSDoc annotations, for example:

```
/**
 * @param {String} x A string
 * @returns {Object} Counted occurrences of characters in x
 */
var charFreq = function(x) {
  return x.split('').reduce(function(acc, x) {
    acc[x] = ++acc[x] || 1;
    return acc;
  },{});
};
```

Comment: Thanks man! I basically only know arrays, objects, and for/while loops, so a lot of what you said is over my head, but I'll get to it eventually I guess! Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

`translate()` is best done using [regular expression substitution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).  (It's unclear from the problem specification how uppercase inputs should be handled.)

```
function translate(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, '$1o$1');
}
```

---

Your `sum()` and `multiply()` are fine, except that you forgot to declare `var i`, so it's global.  As a nitpick, I'd rename `total` → `product` in `multiply()`.  You *could* write them more succinctly as

```
function sum(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(n, total) { return total + n; });
}

function multiply(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(n, product) { return product * n; });
}
```

However, that's not necessarily better than your original code.  For one thing, the one-liner version is about 10× slower.

---

Your `reverse()` is inefficient.  By appending one character at a time to the array, the machine is unable to tell how large the array should be, and therefore may need to silently reallocate the array if it turns out that it needs to be longer than it guessed.  By appending one character at a time to the resulting string, you make it take O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time, since each append operation results in a new string, necessitating the entire intermediate string to be copied.

This should be faster.  The one-liner by @elclanrs would also be quite good.

```
function reverse(string) {
    var rev = new Array(string.length);
    for (var i = string.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rev[i] = string[string.length - i - 1];
    }
    return rev.join('');
}
```

---

`findLongestWord()` is misnamed, in my opinion.  You want the *length* of the longest word, not the word itself.

Again, you forgot to declare `var i`.

I'd prefer a higher-level functional approach, as `Math.max()` and `word.length` provide better hints at the purpose of the code, and therefore make it more readable in my opinion.  However, your approach isn't bad.  Note that my version returns `-Infinity` for an empty array; if you want 0 then you would have to insert a conditional.

```
function findLongestWordLength(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, array.map(function(word) {
                return word.length;
           }));
}
```

---

Your `charFreq()` is fine, but I'd tweak it to be more concise.

```
function charFreq(string) {
    var freq = {};
    for (var i = string.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        freq[string[i]] = 1 + (freq[string[i]] || 0);
    }
    return freq;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `''` instead of `""` wherever possible.  In most languages the content of the double quotes gets interpreted, so the single quote version is faster and does not leak variables.

I'm not sure if it is better, but you can define functions like this too:

```
function findLongestWord(array) {
```

instead of

```
var findLongestWord = function(array) {
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a little more explanation *why* changing the quotes would improve the code. It sounds to me just like a style that may vary from person to person, but where one is not objectively better than the other.

Comment: Javascript does not have string interpolation so that does not affect anything here.

Comment: Functional declarations in javascript are usually frowned upon because they are set at compile time rather than run-time which leads to unexpected behaviors. Usually better to use function expressions (var funcName = ...).

Comment: @cbojar there is string interpolation in coffeescript though <3

Comment: Using single-quotes avoids the need to escape double-quotes when building HTML manually: `'<a href="foo">'` vs. `"<a href=\"foo\">"`.